# PHP Function date() in Codeigniter and Timezones

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime

Why in now that date is **2011/10/31** codeigniter display to me date **2011/10/30**, by following code.

```
<?php
    echo date("Y/m/d");// Output in codeigniter is: 2011/10/30
?>
```

How can I make it output my date and not the server's date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all of my applications, I set the default timezone using this function: (usually, as you suggested, in a 'config' or 'init' file)

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

[List of Supported Timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

The basic idea is to run that ***once*** every time your application loads, and before any times are calculated/parsed; You know your applications best, and so will need to decide the best way to achieve this.

For example just set it in the `php.ini` or for codeigniter in `config/config.php`.

Comment: Output is this: `2011/10/30 CET`

Comment: @JimBo So your server is running Central European Time; you can use the method in my answer to set it to the appropriate TZ

Comment: OK, how can put it(date_default_timezone_set) in config.php for runing always?

Comment: @JimBo Yup, it is as simple as using that function call once during the initialization of your application.

Comment: I put it in a my library:class:__construct and run it library:class in autoload.php and all dates set with my timezone, do this is true?

Comment: @Shad: Added it to the question - err answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Better just to use gmdate instead of date.

This will output Greenwich Mean Time and you can add or remove as many hours as you like.